# ipcMain event.reply not performing its intended function

Tags: javascript, electron

I am developing a simple electron program. It takes a user input from a website, then calls a function with a callback which processes the user input, either returning an error or null (for no error). When an event.reply is used within the call function, it does not throw an error, however it does not run the code specified in the reply. isSuccess is a boolean.

The actual function with a callback, as well as the page's HTML have not been given. In an attempt to solve this problem, I have extensively tested both in a vacuum, and both are not the problem.

node integration is set to `true` and context isolation has been set to `false`.

pageRenderer.js

```
submit = document.getElementById('submit');

ipcRenderer.on('returnInfo', (event, isSuccess) => {
    if (isSuccess) { 
        alert('Success!');
    } else { //Login failed
        alert('Failure!');
    }
});

submit.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const userInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
    ipcRenderer.send('Process', (userInput));
});
```

main.js

```
ipcMain.on('Process', (event, userInput) => {
        globalVariable = userInput
        processValue((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                event.reply('returnInfo', false);
            } else {
                event.reply('returnInfo', true);
            }

        });
});
```

Upon running the program, I tested, using `console.log` within the ipcMain function, that the if statement worked correctly, depending on if `processValue` succeeded or not. It does and does run the code within the if statement, but the ipcRenderer function is not run. The program does not throw a runtime error.

I have been trying for hours to diagnose this issue, but I simply unable to figure out WHY it does not work.

Comment: The code you provided is correct, something else must be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure as to why this works, but I found a solution. **Turns out, immediately after the eventlistener, adding `event.preventDefault();` fixed my issue.** This may cause issues in the future, but it works for now.

```
submit.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
event.preventDefault(); //New line, fixes my issue.
const userInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
ipcRenderer.send('Process', (userInput));
});
```

Anyone have any idea WHY this works? If so, please comment.